# Python. Создать список на основе длины другого списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

День добрый.

У меня есть список

```
y = [348, 336, 330, 340, 332, 333, 344, 348, 349, 354, 375, 379, 365, 356, 341, 312, 300, 294, 304, 323].
```

Как создать другой список, длина которого равна длине списка у и начинаться будет от нуля.
Попробовал вот так:

```
y = [348, 336, 330, 340, 332, 333, 344, 348, 349, 354, 375, 379, 365, 356, 341, 312, 300, 294, 304, 323]
x = []
for i in range(len(x)):
    x[i] = y[i]
    x.append(x)
print(x)
```

Он выводит мне пустой список

```
[]
```

А нужно

```
х = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Comment: x = list(range(len(y)))

Comment: у вас в коде две ошибки. первая -  `for i in range(len(x)):`
а надо было `for i in range(len( y)):`
вот  и выдает вам список длины ноль))
Вторую - сами видите теперь ))

Answer (score 7):

Функция `range` генерирует последовательность, поэтому тут можно без цикла обойтись:

```
y = [348, 336, 330, 340, 332, 333, 344, 348, 349, 354, 375, 379, 365, 356, 341, 312, 300, 294, 304, 323]
x = list(range(len(y)))
print(x)
```

Вариант с вложенными друг в друга функциями может показаться запутанным, а генератор списка, думаю, будет выглядеть проще:

```
x = [i for i in range(len(y))]
```

---

Мне стало интересно замерить скорость работы алгоритмов заполнения списка.

Вариант с `list(range(len(y)))` является самым быстрым:

```
from timeit import timeit


y = [348, 336, 330, 340, 332, 333, 344, 348, 349, 354, 375, 379, 365, 356, 341, 312, 300, 294, 304, 323]
test_globals = dict(y=y)

t = timeit('x = list(range(len(y)))', globals=test_globals)
print(f'Elapsed: {t:.3f} secs')

t = timeit('x = [i for i in range(len(y))]', globals=test_globals)
print(f'Elapsed: {t:.3f} secs')

t = timeit('''
x = []
for i in range(len(y)):
    x.append(i)
''', globals=test_globals)
print(f'Elapsed: {t:.3f} secs')

t = timeit('''
x = list()
for i in range(len(y)):
    x.append(i)
''', globals=test_globals)
print(f'Elapsed: {t:.3f} secs')
```

Результаты:

```
Elapsed: 0.546 secs
Elapsed: 0.875 secs
Elapsed: 1.415 secs
Elapsed: 1.515 secs
```

Comment: Да, этот вариант полегче наверное.

Comment: @Rashid-s, он легче в плане минимализма :)

Comment: А какой вариант лучше? С циклом for или x = list(range(len(y))) ?

Comment: @Rashid-s, знаете, в данном случае мне больше нравится `list(range(len(y)))`, но вариант с `[i for i in range(len(y))]` тоже хороший,  и с циклом тоже имеет право. Просто, тут нужно смотреть на задачу. Если при генерации цикла нужно сделать много действий, которые не уложатся в одну строку (или уложатся, но будет выглядеть это некрасиво), то цикл самое то. Думаю, я добавлю к ответу небольшой замер выполнения кода, думаю это интересно

Answer (score 3):

Скорее вот так

```
y = [348, 336, 330, 340, 332, 333, 344, 348, 349, 354, 375, 379, 365, 356, 341, 312, 300, 294, 304, 323]
x = []
for i in range(len(y)):
    x.append(i)
print(x)
```

Answer (score 2):

Генератор списка в помощь. Очень полезная штука;)

`print([i for i in range(len(y))])`